# iPhone - How to add a new line within a SQLite result to UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I'm reading some content from database using SQLite.

It then will be shown in a `UIAlertView`.

The content contains some new line symbol "\n".

However, it doesn't create a new line in the alert. Instead, the "\n" is shown.

Following is portion of my code:

```
description = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatementE, 0)];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"something" message:description delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
```

Is there anything I can do to make it recognisable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

string with new line character will work without any spl implementation

example

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Print " message:@"line1\nline2\nline3\nline4" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

just Print and check whether your description belongs to following format

Comment: Thanks. The string was loaded from the result of SQL and saved in a NSString description. When I put the description in place, I think it doesn't convert to the right char set that UIAlertView would recognise.